# npm installation of react-native-cli fails

Tags: react-native, failed-installation

I'm trying to get started with React Native on Mac. I installed *Homebrew*, then *Node*, then *Watchman* (according to instructions at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

When I do `npm install -g react-native-cli` (even with `sudo`) I get this:

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:75:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some known issues with npm global package installs (-g) with Node installed via Homebrew on OSX. The link below has instructions on how those can be resolved.

[Fixing npm On Mac OS X for Homebrew Users](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689)

Alternatively you can uninstall Node via Homebrew:

`brew uninstall node`

Then reinstall Node/npm from the Node.js [website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: I uninstalled Node and reinstalled it from the Node.js website as suggested and could then run the `react-native-cli` install command successfully. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all, I'm happy to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help other users who might stumble across this question.